# Is this sort of business classifies as Riba?

Tags: riba

My situation requires me to buy a car. It is really mandatory, not for luxury purpose. I really need it because of the cold weather and for transporting my kids to school. I have waited so long to be able to save money and buy a car, but I couldn't because what I earned was spent for paying rent, school fee, food, and helping my old parents back in Asia.

Cars in Europe are damn expensive because of the tax. I searched a lot to find Qarz Hasanna, meaning a loan without Riba interest, but nobody gives me money unless I sign a contract and I make the 100% guaranteed pledge of paying off the loan in the given time, which is 13 months, on a monthly basis according the tolerance of my monthly budget. Unfortunately, there is no Islamic banking available in Europe and I am struggling with this dilemma. Of course I seek help from Allah to help me as he promised from an unimaginable source.

I finally found a Muslim car dealership saying that he will give me loan with one condition. The price of the car if paid all now will be cheaper than if I pay it on the monthly installment as a loan. The difference is big, but he does not call it interest. He says that it is a fee for processing the loan (claiming that it's just like the Islamic banking style); just with different name. Is it permissible to enter to this kind of deal? Would it not be Riba? I have never dealt with an Islamic banking loan before, so I don't have previous knowledge of Islamic banking. Therefore I don't know whether this guy who offered me loan by calling it processing fee is right or wrong. I need your urgent help in shedding light on this problem whether the referred arrangement is riba or not?

Comment: While the answer given below is sufficient, I also recommend you read this Q&A: [Why is Murabaha not considered Riba?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/why-is-murabaha-not-considered-riba)

Answer (score 2):

This is called ***Bay' bi At-taqsit***.

From what I know, some Oulamas (Ath-Thawri, Al-Awzaï, Al-Albani) say that is not permitted, because they consider it *Riba*. But there's other Oulamas, like Malek, Abou Hanifa, Ach-Chafiï, that refute this judgement, and have arguments to do so (too long for me to share them here).

But to resume what they're saying, if the **price is fixed from the beginning** of the transaction, **without possibility of increasing it afterwards**, at any condition (like an exceeded payment delay), then they don't consider it *Riba*.

And God knows best.